# Disproving onto functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm so confused with inverse function with their proofing and disproving which is giving me a big headache.

For instance the question is,

> Consider the function $F$ on the interval
>
> $[-1, 1]  = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 \leq x \leq 1\}$, given by $F = \{(x, y): y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}\}$
>
> Since $F$ is a relation, there is an inverse relation $F^{-1}$ on $[-1, 1]$ given by $F^{-1} = \{(x, y): y = \pm\sqrt{1 - x^2}\}$

Then it immediately jumps to the next line and says $F^{-1}$ is not a function since F is neither one-to-one nor onto.

I do understand one-to-one is definitely not possible because $x$ is a square which means that the outcome of a negative $x$ or a positive $x$ will definitely be positive.

However as for onto, it's disproving method is that find $y \in B$ which is not an image of another $x \in A$.

The question is how do I identify the $A$ and the $B$ for this function? I'm so confused with how to proof or disproof any onto functions.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Based on the information you included in the highlighted box, it appears that $F: [-1, 1] \to [-1, 1]$.  I drew this conclusion based on the fact that both $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are defined on $[-1, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain of the function under discussion. In this case it would be the domain and codomain of $F$. You need to show that there exists an element of $B$ that is not equal to $F(x)$ where $x$ is some element of $A$. If $F: [-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then clearly the negative real numbers are not in the image of $F$.

Comment: Where do they exactly get the value [-1, 1] from and what do they mean? Can i say that A is a the domain ( which means all value of the x-axis ) while B is the codomain  (which means all values of the y-axis)? Why would you say negative real number is not an image of F(x) ?

Comment: Note that $F^{-1}$ is also defined on $[-1, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain ($A$) and codomain ($B$) of the function should always be specified by the person who defines the function.

In this case, the text says : "Consider the function $F$ on the interval $[-1, 1]$", that means that the domain $A$ is $[-1,1]$.

The text does not say anything about the codomain $B$, so it can be any set containing the image of A (and in this precise case, the image of $A$ by $F$ is $[0,1]$).

As it is often the case, you have to infer $B$ from the context. Here it could be for example $[-1,1]$, or $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Note that $F^{-1}$ is also defined on $[-1, 1]$.